# ServiceStack POST,PUT, DELETE method not working

Tags: servicestack

I am newbie to servicestack and somehow my POST,PUT and DELETE methods are not working.

Error - ServiceStack.WebException: Method Not Allowed
ErrorCode - NotImplementedException

Though the GET method is working as expected!

Any suggestion why am I getting such error.

Service Request Code Sample -

```
[Route("/students", "POST")]
public class CreateStudent : IReturn<StudentDTO>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Service Response -

```
public StudentDTO Post(CreateStudent request)
    {
        var student = new Student()
        {
            Id = request.Id,
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            LastName = request.LastName
        };

        using (var connection = this.OpenDbConnection())
        {
            connection.Insert(student);
        }

        return Mapper.Map<StudentDTO>(student);
    }
```

This is how I am calling it -

```
var student = new Student
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            FirstName = "FirstName",
            LastName = "LastName"
        };

        var response = this.Client.Post(student);
```

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: This is nowhere near enough information to be able to identify the issue. Please provide the source code for your Service implementation, your Request DTO with any defined Routes as well as how you're calling the Service and any more details about the error, e.g. the raw HTTP Response (you can get using Fiddler or WebInspector).

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Request DTO is `CreateStudent` but you're posting a completely different `Student` DTO, change it to use the Request DTO, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl);

var request = new CreateStudent
{
    FirstName = "FirstName",
    LastName = "LastName"
};

var response = client.Post(request);
```

Comment: Oh God, I could have figure it out! Thanks a lot!